# Uso de "rufián" como "hombre dedicado al tráfico de la prostitución"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, sinónimos, españa

El DRAE define [**rufián**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WnxwBK0) como

> Quizá del it. ruffiano, y este der. del lat. rufus 'pelirrojo', 'rubio', por alus. a la costumbre de las meretrices romanas de adornarse con pelucas rubias.
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona sin honor, perversa, despreciable.
> 2. m. **Hombre dedicado al tráfico de la prostitución.**

¿Es común utilizarla con esa segunda acepción (que yo hasta ahora desconocía)?

¿Es, entonces, un sinónimo de **proxeneta** y de **chulo**, o hay algún matiz diferenciador?

Comment: Enntu mismo enlace `Quizá del it. ruffiano, y este der. del lat.rufus 'pelirrojo', 'rubio', por alus. a la costumbre de las meretrices romanas de adornarse con pelucas rubias.`... Tiene pinta de que sí, va en esa línea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En España, a día de hoy, yo solo reconozco el uso de la primera acepción (*Persona sin honor, perversa, despreciable*). La segunda (*Hombre dedicado al tráfico de la prostitución*) no creo que se entienda de primeras, por lo que podría afirmar que no es nada común actualmente.

En cuanto a si es sinónimo de proxeneta y chulo, parece que sí lo fue en su momento. Véamoslo:

Por lo que he podido ver, la evolución histórica va desde la acepción de proxeneta a una actual más genérica.

Es interesante ver la evolución de las acepciones de esta palabra. Para empezar, en el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) vemos que la acepción más utilizada actualmente solo se incluyó en 1884.

> fig. Hombre sin honor, perverso, despreciable.

En cambio, la que comentas ya figuraba en 1780. A continuación detallo cómo:

**1780**

> s. m. El que trata y vive deshonestamente con mugeres, solicitándolas, ó consitiéndolas el trato con otros hombres. Llámase así tambien el que por causas torpes riñe sus pendencias. Leno.

**1817**

> s. m. El que trata y vive deshonestamente con mugeres, solicitándolas ó consintiéndoles el trato con otros hombres. Llámase asi tambien el que por causas torpes tiene pendencias. Leno, machus.

**1884**, **1925** y **1992**

> m. El que hace el infame tráfico de mujeres públicas.

**2001**

> 1. m. Hombre que hace el infame tráfico de mujeres públicas.

**2014 (actual)**

> m. Hombre dedicado al tráfico de la prostitución.

Pero es que incluso antes ya constaba: mirando en el [Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) vemos por ejemplo que en **1591** la palabra era una variación de *rofian*, la cual ya aparece incluso en **1495** definida como *alcauete, leno, onis*.

Luego, en **1611** (Rosal) leemos:

> Rufián, o rubo, amigo de ramera, y rufa la tal amiga. De estos vocablos usaron los latinos muchas veces. Y porque Rufo es lo mesmo de roxo o bermejo, dice Servio Gramatico, que los llamaron Roxos, porque las Rameras entre los Pastores de Roma vestían pieles de cabra roxa o de zorra. Digo yo, que debió ser insignia de la Ramera, como Hieroglifico que fué d ela Luxuria, de donde quizás quedó el llamarlas Pellejas, aunque en su lugar se trata mejor de esto. Assensio dice, que porque los de este pelo son salaces o libidinosos, parece ser, porque el pelo roxo fue tenido por gala y hermosura, como notamos en el Ultimo Alfabeto, y la hermosura suele ser aparejo, y causa de tales yerros segun dice Ovidio, Cpist [?]
>
> Sis est cum forma magna pudicitie
>
> Demás de esto pudo ser la causa que los Romanos vestian y señalaban las Rameras con unas togas de tela clara transparente y roxa, dicen que por el color del oro, y por cuya cudicia usaban su mal trato; yo pienso que porque el color roxo fue insignia del amor lascivo, y libidinoso, como notamos en el Ultimo Alfabeto. A esto alude Virgilio quando dice = Inde Lupe fulvo Nutricis tegmine letus / Romulus excipiet gentem [?]
> Sino es de un verbo Ruph, que significa hacer temblar, o rendir a otro; y parece asi, pues los Rufianes son Guardas y vengadores de las ruines mugeres y siempre nos los pintan bravos y matadores.

Mi interpretación de todo esto es que el *rol* de proxeneta era seguramente bastante más común en la edad media. Poco a poco, sus costumbres se fueron identificando con una forma de ser, hasta alcanzar a definir todo aquel que actúa así, sin por ello ser un proxeneta.

Google Ngram nos da una visión de la evolución en el uso de la palabra ([rufián/rufian](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rufi%C3%A1n%2Crufian&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crufi%C3%A1n%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crufian%3B%2Cc0)):

[image]

Se observa su generalización hacia 1900, un descenso hacia 1950 y un repunte significativo a principios de la década de 2000. Un análisis rápido de las entradas que usan este término nos hacen ver que, en general, se trata de republicaciones o análisis de libros antiguos (Cervantes, Lope de Vega...).

Answer (score 0):

No, coloquialmente no se le relaciona con esa función, y tal vez es debido a que existen muchas palabras para la "profesión" que son muy populares, como proxeneta, chulo, dandy, padrote.

Sin embargo, decir *un rufián en todos los sentidos* debería ser aceptado cuando todo el perfil del personaje en cuestión está dibujado.